# Interpreting linux lockdep

Tags: linux, locking, kernel

I'm new to linux lockdep feature and I'm trying to understand it. I read appropriate doc in linux kernel lockdep-design.txt however I'm not sure if I interprete it correctly.
Let's say we have two lines from lockdep:

```
1. c88c9354 OPS:       1 FD:    1 BD:    2 +.-...: &rwlok
2. c88f1354 OPS:       1 FD:    1 BD:    1 .+.-..: &rwlok
```

In first line - does it mean that lock has been acquired for writing with HW irqs enabled and in soft-irq context?

Is that correct?
What about the second one?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/lockdep-design.txt)